# Mapping to <S-Right> and <S-Left>

Tags: vimperator, pentadactyl

I'd like to map `C-n` and `C-p` to `S-Right` and `S-Left` correspondingly. I tried to put

```
cmap <C-n> <S-Right>
cmap <C-p> <S-Left>
```

in ~/.pentadactylrc - but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: Putting those in my `.pentadactylrc` works fine for me. What version are you using? (Mine is Pentadactyl 1.0b8pre-hg6437-default (created 2011/09/02 19:50:06) running on: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:6.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.1)

Comment: Oh... <C-n> switches to the next tab. I wanted <S-Right> to do it as well. But when I put `cmap <C-n> <S-Right>` - <S-Right> doesn't work this way (I press Esc several times - and then try <S-Right> - it doesn't switch to the next tab, contrast to <C-n>).

Comment: `cmap` is for command line mode, not normal mode, and you've got it backwards. I'll post as an answer, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different mapping commands for different modes. `cmap` is for command line mode, and wouldn't affect what happens after hitting Escape a few times, since hitting Escape a few times would put you back in normal mode.

Most likely what you want to do is create a mapping for normal mode. When using these commands, the first argument is the map you're creating, and the second argument is what you're mapping it to.

```
nmap <S-Right> <C-n>
nmap <S-Left> <C-p>
```

Or better (because you could then remap `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` if you wanted:

```
nnoremap <S-Right> <C-n>
nnoremap <S-Left> <C-p>
```

For further help for different mapping commands, type `:help map` in pentadactyl.

Comment: `:help map` is what I had to try first...